# Is there a generalization of the nested interval theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I'm familiar with the nested interval theorem on the real line. But is there a generalization of such a theorem in literature?

Comment: Maybe this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals#Higher_dimensions

Comment: It is called "completeness". The nested interval property on IR is equivalent to the fact that every Cauchy sequence converges (which is the definition of completeness). EDIT: But maybe this is not what you wanted to hear... ;-)

Comment: @amsmath Well, thanks. That's great also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a generalization to metric and Hausdorff topological spaces. Any nested sequence of non-empty compact subsets has  non-empty intersection. For metric spaces, if the diameter approaches zero, the intersection is one point. So for $\mathbb{R}^n$, any nested sequence of (closed) boxes or closed balls has non-empty intersection.

Actually, more is true (finite intersection property): If a family of compact sets has the property that the intersection of any finite number of them is non-empty, then their intersection is non-empty. Obviously nested families enjoy the finite intersection property.

Comment: I didn't study Hausdorff topological spaces. But I had an immature intuition  :) that if we wanted the intersection of the boxes to intersect in a single point. We would we impose that their Lebesgue measure goes to zero, why do we need their dia $\to$ 0 and not their Lebesgue measure?

Comment: In a generic metric space there is no such a thing like Lebesgue measure ( I am not aware of any canonical construction) Measure theoretical considerations seem to me foreign to the question. If diam goes to zero you get a unique intersection point. In R^n if the measure goes to zero you can have say a whole segment or any other lower dimensional object as your intersection.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, suppose we have compact sets $X = U_0\supset U_1\supset U_2 \supset \cdots$ in some arbitrary compact, Hausdorff space $X$. If $\bigcap U_i$ is empty, then the sets $V_i = X\setminus U_i$ form an open cover of $X$ and must therefore admit a finite subcover; that is, some $U_i$ is empty.

(If you're not familiar with compact spaces, the key points are that bounded, closed subspsaces of $\mathbb{R}^N$ (e.g., closed boxes) satisfy the hypothesis above; and for $X$ compact, by definition any open sets $U_i\subset X$ with $\bigcup U_i = X$ have $\bigcup_{i\in S} U_i = X$ for a finite set $S$.)